# In jQuery, given a select menu element, how do I access the first option element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-selectmenu

Given a jQuery element like so:

```
$(selectElt)
```

How do I access the first option?  Note I am not interested in a selector given the select menu's id, e.g.

```
$('#selectmenu1 option:first')
```

What I am given is the select element itself, `$(selectElt)`, from which I need to select the first option element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
$(selectElt).children("option:first");
```

or

```
$(selectElt).children("option:eq(0)");
```

or

```
$(selectElt).children("option:nth-child(1)");
```

or contextually:

```
$("option:first", selectElt)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
$(selectElt).children('option').eq(0)
```

or

```
$(selectElt).children('option:first')
```

or

```
$(selectElt).children('option').first()
```

As RoryMcCrossan said

```
$('option:first',selectElt)
```

And the last one

```
$(selectElt).children('option').filter(':first')
```

Comment: Just for completeness there's also contextual selector: `$('option:first', selectElt)`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Forgot about that, and the fvaleri reminded me about the filter :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
$(selectElt).filter(":first")
```